# C++ - WINAPI - Raw input specific functions and structures missing?

Tags: c++, winapi, input, user-input

While trying to use raw input specific functions and structures in WINAPI using MinGW in Code::Blocks IDE, I got lots of compiler errors for missing functions and structures:

```
> ||In function 'void find_devices_input()':| |16|error:
> 'RAWINPUTDEVICELIST' was not declared in this scope| |16|error:
> 'GetRawInputDeviceList' was not declared in this scope| |19|error:
> 'list_devices_input' was not declared in this scope| |19|error:
> expected type-specifier before 'RAWINPUTDEVICELIST'| |19|error:
> expected ';' before 'RAWINPUTDEVICELIST'| |25|error: type '<type
> error>' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer| ||=== Build
> finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Why does this happen and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler errors occur because of missing preprocessor definition. Based on these general questions and answers found [here](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/month=20091001), this piece of code will fix it:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
#   define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif // __MINGW32__
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: I recommend using [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) instead, and you won't have to worry about stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because

> 'RAWINPUTDEVICELIST' was not declared in this scope

etc.

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say to `#include <Windows.h>`

Comment: Well, this might be the case for Microsoft Visual Studio and other IDEs, but for MinGW in Code::Blocks, this won't unfortunately cut it. I believe MinGW headers aren't as accurate as they should be. I'm not an expert on this subject, just wanted to help those out, who have similiar problems as I do. :)